# IncompatibleClassChangeError while running JAXB on Unix AIX

Tags: java, jaxb2

I get a **java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError** when i try to run my project on **AIX machine**.

- The project generate XML files using **JAXB API (2.0)**.
- The development environment installed in **Windows XP** and **use JDK1.5.0**(the same JDK as AIX machine ones).
- In the developement environment the project works good. but in the AIX machine it doesn't work (throws the exception).

Here is the stack trace when I try to run the project :

```
........................./build.xml:176: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.size(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:82)
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.hasNext(AbstractList.java:431)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:260)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:104)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:214)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:99)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:320)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RegistryInfoImpl.<init>(RegistryInfoImpl.java:103)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.addRegistry(ModelBuilder.java:362)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:332)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:460)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:298)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:141)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1163)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:145)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:236)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:615)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:186)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:146)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:348)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:446)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:409)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:313)
at gen.utils.Util.unmarshalling(Unknown Source)
at gen.utils.Util.mvtConfig(Unknown Source)
at gen.utils.Util.mvtGenConfig(Unknown Source)
at gen.start.StartGen.mvtGeneration(Unknown Source)
at gen.start.StartGen.start(Unknown Source)
at gen.start.StartGen.main(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:615)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.run(ExecuteJava.java:217)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:152)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.run(Java.java:771)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:221)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:135)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:108)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:615)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

Please help. 
Thanks.

Comment: Try deleting all `*.class` files and recompile them from source. If that doesn't help, edit the XML file to narrow down the problem, and then paste the problematic XML code along with an outline (i.e. method signatures, annotations) of the involved class(es).

Answer (score 1):

Check your classpath on AIX and make sure you are using compatible versions of jaxb-api and jaxb-impl libraries. I have encountered IncompatibleClassChangeError when only the minor version is different by one increment (e.g. 2.2.5 versus 2.2.6).

To check what version of each library you are using and what is required for compatibility, look in the manifest file located in the META-INF directory within each jar file. The jaxb-impl manifest declares (in addition to its own version) the specification-version, which is the version of jaxb-api jar that it requires. Since v2.2.2, the version numbers of compatible instances of jaxb-api and jaxb-impl no longer match: e.g. jaxb-impl v2.2.4 is compatible with jaxb-api v2.2.3

I only have experience using the Sun implementation of JAXB (com.sun.xml.bind), so this might not apply if you are using a different implementation.